# Occupation Column on Passenger List

Tags: occupation, 1850s

On the Mar 9, 1853 Passenger List for the Shannon, what does “do” in the Occupation Column for a child mean?

Comment: Probably "ditto"; as in "same as the person immediately above"

Comment: Where did the Shannon sail from and to in 1853?